# Why do we need admittance, susceptance and conductance?

Tags: power, impedance, transmission-line, load, high-power

What is the need for modelling circuits and transmission lines, and loads using variables stated above when we can use resistance in the real domain and reactance in the imaginary domain. Are not the basic parameters enough to convey the ease of passage for current and the push-back (resistance or reactance). In fact isn't Y = G + jB is the same thing as Z = R + jX. Please explain the need for the former when we have the latter

Comment: Sometimes, it is easyer talking with Y or with Z. Smith chart works also with z or y.

Comment: ` Y = G + jB is the same thing as Z = R + jX.` er no. They are both true, which is different to saying they are the 'same thing'. The reason we have both is that they are not the same thing.

Comment: Admittance simplifies calculations with parallel elements and impedance  simplies calculations with series elements.

Answer (score 0):

> In fact Y = G + jB is the same thing as Z = R + jX.

If \$Y = 1/Z\$ and \$Z=R+jX\$, then

$$ Y = 1/Z = \frac{1}{R+jX} = \frac{R-jX}{R^2+X^2}$$

If, \$G = 1/R\$
and
\$B = 1/X\$ then

$$G + jB = \frac{1}{R} + \frac{j}{X}$$

As a general rule (with exceptions)

$$\frac{R-jX}{R^2+X^2} \ne \frac{1}{R} + \frac{j}{X}$$

even though the both have the same form of \$a + jb\$.

Answer (score 0):

> Are not the basic parameters enough...

There's nothing more "basic" about impedance than admittance, or of resistance than conductance.

These concepts are related by the principle of *duality*, and are equally valid and equally fundamental in circuit theory.

You should learn to consider both of the dual formulations of a circuit analysis (for example, consider the mesh equations as equally valid as the node equations). You will often find that one or the other formulation is easier for a given circuit. By considering both you have the best chance to find the simplest way to solve a circuit.

(Also realize that the node analysis that you use every time you use SPICE or a derivative program to solve a circuit is based on the admittance representation of the circuit equations, not the impedance representation)